# Port Forwarding for compute engine google cloud platform

Tags: port, google-compute-engine, firewall, forwarding

I'm trying to open port TCP 28016 and UDP 28015 for a game server in my compute engine VM running on Microsoft Windows Server 2016.

I've tried opening the opening inside my server using RDP, going to Windows Firewall setting and creating new inbound rules for both TCP 28016 and UDP 28015.
Also done setting firewall rules on my Cloud Platform Firewall Rules for both port.

When running my game server application, running netstat didn't show any of the port being used / not listening . Not even shows up. What did i do wrong ?

Edit : it now shows up on netstat -a -b , but didn't have LISTENING

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't show as `LISTENING`, it's not a firewall or "port forwarding" issue; rather, the application either isn't running, or is running but isn't configured to listen for connections on that port.